# What do these red bullseye icons mean in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Does anyone[image] know what these red bullseye icons mean?  I'm having trouble launching my react-native app after implementing cocoapods. Is there are a comprehensive list of all icons and their meaning in Xcode, I've looked haven't found anything.

Comment: I'm guessing also these icons can differentiate between a "target" and "library" but was hoping it may be the source of why my app is failing to compile.  TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both types of icons shown here are a visual pun of sorts.

The red bullseye icons are **targets**. (Like the kind you throw darts at.)

The white building icons are **libraries**. (Like the kind you get books from.)

Comment: Is there a definitive list you're aware of defining all icons in Xcode?  Much appreciation for your response.

Comment: why they all are listed under the section "TARGETS" ?